# text-overflow: ellipsis is not working on IE10

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10, ellipse

```
p.details {
    font-size:     12px;
    color:         #6D6D6D;
    white-space:   nowrap;
    width:         100%;
    overflow:      hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-height:    3.6em;
    line-height:   1.8em;
    min-height:    3.6em;
}
```

the above css works fine on chrome, firefox, safari except for IE10. it's supposed to have a "..." behind the sentence if it's too long.

For example: "These are the details of the ..." instead of "These are the details of the promotion items"

Please help!

New update: i've removed word-wrap: break-word and it worked for the first line. the subsequent line(s) won't work. 
For example:

```
<p class = "details">"- Sentence 1" <br> "- Sentence 2" </p>
```

This will produce:

Senten...
Sentence

Comment: are you sure this works in Firefox? I just tried (FF 23) and it didn't. If I am correct, I don't think `ellipsis` would work with `word-wrap` and `width:100%`.

Comment: Yes it works on firefox, chrome and safari. Tested :)

Comment: that is strange, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Not sure how to make a fiddle! haha.

Comment: Sorry mate, even with the updated code it doesn't work for me even in the first line. If I give a fixed width (say `width: 50px;`) then it works on both lines.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following line from your styling:

```
word-wrap:     break-word;
```

Comment: Hi! thanks :) i've removed the word-wrap and it works. However, it doesn't work for my 2nd line. It only works for the first line. This is an example of my html:
<p class = "details"> "- Sentence1" <br> "Sentence 2"</p>

Answer (score 0):

IE10 doesnt like the br tag for Ellipsis.
Instead try using a new div for new line feeds and it will start woirking.
Like this

"- Sentence 1"  "- Sentence 2"